# How do I repair and clean a loose, greasy washing machine drum?

Tags: repair, washing-machine, laundry

After washing some bulky items, my washing machine drum became loose and makes a loud, clanking noise on the spin cycle regardless of the size of the load. It feels as if the drum is almost detached. Since the drum broke, it deposits grease stains and residue on my laundry. My question is two-fold, as I **think** the problems are related:

- How do I repair the drum, so that it doesn't continue to emit a loud, clanking noise?
- How do I clean the drum, so that it no longer leaves grease stains and residue on my laundry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a bad drum hub nut. This is a very common failure of a top load washing machine. Look up your model on a few of the any repair parts sites and locate the hub nut. I suggest replacing the all the parts in the process of the replacing the nut. Should be fairly inexpensive for the parts. The procedure usually involves removing the entire machine casing. Make sure you have the machine unplugged.
As far as cleaning, go ahead and use a simple green type product and clean the edges of the inner and outer tub.
If it is the transmission area, then you have a bigger problem. But I bet it is more likely the hub nut.